# Dagger component body

Tags: dagger-2, dagger

I am pretty new to Dagger and finding the component body a bit difficult to understand,having 2 specific questions related to the component implementation:

1)

```
  @Singleton
    @Component(modules = { UserModule.class, BackEndServiceModule.class })
    public interface MyComponent {

        BackendService provideBackendService();// Line 1

        void inject(Main main); // Line 2
    }
```

What is the purpose of Line 2? also will an instance of backendService be created even if line 1 is removed?

and also in the below code where the implementation of the above interface is generated , what does the component.inject(this) actually do?

```
public class Main {

@Inject
BackendService backendService; // 

private MyComponent component;

private Main() {
    component = DaggerMyComponent.builder().build();
    component.inject(this);
}

private void callServer() {
    boolean callServer = backendService.callServer();
    if (callServer) {
        System.out.println("Server call was successful. ");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Server call failed. ");
    }
}
```

and also why has the backendservice not obtained using component.provideBackendService()

Answer (score 1):

> What is the purpose of `void inject(Main main);`?

It lets you perform `field injection` on concrete class `Main`, assuming that `Main` is a class that *cannot* be created by Dagger

> where the implementation of the above interface is generated , what does the component.inject(this) actually do?

It uses `MemberInjector`s to inject the package-protected or public fields marked with `@Inject`. You can see the implementation of `inject(Main)` method in `DaggerMyComponent` class.

---

Of course, **if possible** it is better to make it so that:

1.) Main does not instantiate/know about its own injector

2.) Main is created by the Dagger component and `@Inject` constructor is used

```
@Singleton
public class Main {    
    private final BackendService backendService;

    @Inject
    Main(BackendService backendService) {
        this.backendService = backendService;
    }
}
```